# Why does a single call of Keras model.predict() use 1.3 GB of Memory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, memory-leaks, keras

I am currently recreating Deepmind's AlphaZero as a personal project using Keras with a TensorFlow backend. During each game simulation, the NN I am using needs to make many predictions. The NN is working as it should but is using an excessive amount of CPU RAM.

I am using `psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss` to print memory usage, and when `model.predict()` is called for the first time, memory usage jumps from around 0.3 GB to 1.6 GB. On consecutive calls, no new memory (or at least very little) is allocated.

I'm not sure if this is expected behavior, but I would like the program to run as efficiently as possible as I would like to run it on TPUs on Google Compute Engine.

Below is the code for my Keras model:

```
main_input = Input(shape = self.input_dim, name = 'main_input', dtype="float32")

x = self.conv_layer(main_input, 256, (3,3))

for i in range(19): # AlphaZero used 19
    x = self.residual_layer(x, 256, (3, 3))

vh = self.value_head(x)
ph = self.policy_head(x)

model = Model(inputs=[main_input], outputs=[vh, ph])
model.compile(loss={'value_head': 'mean_squared_error', 'policy_head': softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits},
    optimizer=SGD(lr=self.learning_rate, momentum = MOMENTUM), #config.MOMENTUM
    loss_weights={'value_head': 0.5, 'policy_head': 0.5}
)
```

The Neural Network is very large, so its size may contribute to the amount of RAM allocated, but 1.6 GB seems unreasonable. Also, if I reduce the model to having only 2 residual layers instead of 19, it still allocates around 1.54 GB instead versus the 1.6 GB used before.

Comment: how many parameters does your model have?

Comment: Probably the batch size requires a lot of memory? 1.6Gb is not a lot...